# I have a light fixture with a green a white and a black wire. What is the green for?

Tags: light-fixture

I have a light fixture with a green wire as well as white and black. Where does green go?

Answer (score 5):

Green is the ground wire. It connects to the ground conductor in the box and bonds it to exposed metal portions of the fixture as a safety measure.

The ground conductor is typically a bare wire inside the same cable as the supply hot and neutral wires. But in some older systems, ground is conducted via a metal jacket or conduit, in which case you would also have a metal box. In those cases, the green wire should be bonded to the box.

Comment: How do you bond to a plastic box?

Answer (score 3):

The green is the Ground it needs to be connected to the bare wire in the box. If you don't have a bare "ground" wire just put a wire nut on the green.